# Python Coverage suddenly dropping

Tags: python, sonarqube, code-coverage, coverage.py

I'm working on a GUI written in Python using PyQt5, and I'm preparing the coverage report for SonarQube.

The coverage was initially 43%. Then it suddenly dropped after I changed the main file, called `app.py`. All I did was add the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I added this because without it, it would display the GUI when importing `app.py`.
The `main()` simply instantiates the application, and also contains instructions to show the main window. With the above addition, the coverage drops to 14%. If I remove the above, the coverage goes right back to 43%. Any ideas why the coverage would suddenly drop significantly upon adding this tiny change, and how I could prevent it from dropping this much?

Versions:

- Python 3.10.2
- Coverage.py, version 6.3.3 with C extension
- PyQt5 5.15.4

Comment: It's `if __name__ == "__main__":`. The file name doesn't matter, the `__main__` is a convention that indicates that the current file is also the *main* script running.

Comment: If I do that, then the application starts up when importing, which is the exact thing I'm trying to avoid. The reason is I'm importing app.py in my tests, and I don't want to display the GUI when running my tests. When I run the pytest command it indeed does not open, but when I run the coverage command it does show the GUI.

Comment: The point is that comparison is meaningless, as there's no such thing as `__app_`, and with that your program wouldn't even run at all, since *that* is the main script but that comparison will never be valid.

Comment: Yea, you're right, I realized that now and i have replaced it. But I still encounter my problem and I don't know how to solve it.